# How to force li from menu to display/hide an element from another div?

Tags: jquery

what should I do to force the li element to show/hide an element from another div?
I thought I can do that using each() but is that a good way?
Thanks!

```
 const menu = $('.menu_list li');
 const pages =$('.pages').children();

 menu.each(function( index ) {
   $(this).on('click', () =>{
     pages[i].addClass('show');
   });
 })
```

[jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/ah02mo4x/5/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the .index() method which returns the index of the current item and toggle menu item display

```
$('.menu_list li').on('click', function(){
   // if you want to show only one a time
   $('.pages').removeClass('show');
   //
   $('.pages').eq($(this).index()).addClass('show');
 });
```

hope help

below the jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/2y1mm0bs/